# Web API authentication With ASP.Net core and Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

How do I create an endpoint for registering and login in a user? I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity for user management.

Answer (score 0):

About the identity configuration, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services). About registering and login, they are similar to normal routing. All method are included in UserManager and SignInManager.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    
    public HomeController(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager
        )
    {
        
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(string username, string password)
    {
        
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = username,
            Email = "",
        };
        
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "amdin");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            
            var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);
            if (signInResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return View("index");
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
   }
```

In this scenario, client need to use cookie container to handle cookie, but jwt is a more efficient way to deal with api.